# Form validation, normal button, red box and clean data

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a popup form and I have to validate fields in this form before I close this popup, I need to use this validation with a normal button, not a submit, if the fields are emty I need to mark these on a red box and put the 'This field is empty' after. After I close the form I need to clean up data from form. How should I do this using jQuery and Javascript?

```
<form id="frmUsers" data-userid="">
        <img id="btnClose" src="resources/img/close_window.png">
        <h2 id="popupTitle"></h2>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <label for="username">Username:</label>
                <input type="text" id="username" name="txtUsername" placeholder="Please select username" class="required"/>
                <p></p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="level">Level:</label>
                <input type="number" id="level" name="txtLevel" placeholder="Please select level"/>
                <p></p>

            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="registrationStatus">RegistrationStatus:</label>
                <select name="txtRegistrationStatus" id="registrationStatus"
                        placeholder="Please select registration status">
                    <option value="Registered">Registered</option>
                    <option value="Unregistered">Unregistered</option>
                </select>
                <p></p>

            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="registrationDate">RegistrationDate:</label>
                <input type="text" id="registrationDate" name="txtRegistrationDate"
                       placeholder="Please select date"/>
                <p></p>
            </li>

            <div class="btnZone">
                <input class="btnDown" type="button" value=" " id="btnPopup" />
                <input class="btnDown" type="button" value="Cancel" id="btnCancel"/>
            </div>
        </ul>
    </form>
```

And my form validation function:

```
function validateForm() {

    var txtUsername = $("#username").val();

    if(txtUsername == ""){
        ("#username").css("border-color", "red");
    }

    // $(":input").each(function () {
    //     if ($(this).val() == "") {
    //         $(this).css("border-color", "red");
    //         // $("p").html("This field is empty");
    //         // $("input").val("This field is required");
    //         // alert($(this).attr("id") & " validate error");
    //     }else{
    //         $(this).css("border-color", "black");
    //     }
    //
    // });
}
```

Comment: Please add the code of your form and the code you got so far.

Comment: Ok. I edit my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of many popup/modal plugins, but if you want to create your own, than you should do something similar to this:

```js
var txtUsername = $("#username");
function validateForm() {
 txtUsernameValid = $.trim(txtUsername.val());
 txtUsername.toggleClass('invalid-input', !txtUsernameValid);
 return txtUsernameValid;
};
$('[data-popup]').each(function(i) {
 var thisButton = $(this);
 var toPopup = $(thisButton.data('popup'));
 toPopup.wrap('<div class="popup-container"><div class="popup-content"></div></div>');
 var popupContainer = toPopup.closest('.popup-container').hide();
 popupContainer.find('.popup-content').append('<span class="popup-close">X</span>')
 thisButton.on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  popupContainer.show();
 });
 popupContainer.find('.popup-close').on('click', function(e) {
  popupContainer.hide();
 });
 popupContainer.find('#btnSave').on('click', function(e) {
  /* Save your data, than reset the form */
  if( validateForm() ) {
   popupContainer.find('form')[0].reset();
   popupContainer.hide();
  };
 });
 popupContainer.find('#btnCancel').on('click', function(e) {
  popupContainer.find('form')[0].reset();
  popupContainer.hide();
 });
});
```

```css
body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
.popup-container {
    background: none rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
.popup-container::before {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.popup-content {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background: none #fff;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    text-align: left;
}
form ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
}
.popup-close {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 4px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    right: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.invalid-input {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button data-popup="#frmUsers">
    Open form
</button>
<form id="frmUsers" data-userid="">
    <img id="btnClose" src="resources/img/close_window.png">
    <h2 id="popupTitle"></h2>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <label for="username">Username:</label>
            <input type="text" id="username" name="txtUsername" placeholder="Please select username" class="required" />
            <p></p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="level">Level:</label>
            <input type="number" id="level" name="txtLevel" placeholder="Please select level" />
            <p></p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="registrationStatus">RegistrationStatus:</label>
            <select name="txtRegistrationStatus" id="registrationStatus" placeholder="Please select registration status">
                <option value="Registered">Registered</option>
                <option value="Unregistered">Unregistered</option>
            </select>
            <p></p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="registrationDate">RegistrationDate:</label>
            <input type="text" id="registrationDate" name="txtRegistrationDate" placeholder="Please select date" />
            <p></p>
        </li>
        <div class="btnZone">
            <input class="btnDown" type="button" value="Save" id="btnSave" />
            <input class="btnDown" type="button" value="Cancel" id="btnCancel" />
        </div>
    </ul>
</form>
```

It is not complicated indeed, but I never try to invent hot water, I just take one of existing plugins, as [Magnific Popup](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/).

Same code on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4Luw5zy2/3/).